# How to assign a name to a symbol in an Excel macro

Tags: worksheet-function, macros, windows-11

In the formula bar in Excel I'd like to block..copy a symbol, assign to it a name, and then use an IF function to determine what to do next; i.e. if NAME is "-", then do A, if not, then do B.
I'd like to do all this in a macro.
Thank you for any input.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.

VBA "sees' the *Formula Bar* as `Activecell.Formula` so if **A1** contains ***$***, then:

```
Sub UsingFormulaBar()
 Dim Dolar As String
 Range("A1").Select
 Dolar = ActiveCell.Formula
End Sub
```

otherwise:

```
Sub NotUsingFormulaBar()
    Dim Dolar As String
    Dolar = "$"
End Sub
```

Comment: If you had written this in ancient Etruscan, I'd understand just as much of it. However, you clearly know what you're talking about, so I've bought a book on VBA, and I'll find out what you've done. I'll let you know how I get on. Thank you very much.